# How to create ContentType with FieldLinks using REST on O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, content-type, rest

I'm trying to create a ContentType with FieldLinks using REST only (no `SP.ClientContext`) on SharePoint Online, but I'm not able to make it work.

Creating ContentType by **POST**ing to `_api/Web/ContentTypes` works fine by itself, the problem is FieldLinks.

Comment: I don't know if you've gotten this sorted out, but I think you have to daisy chain your way through by creating the content type, adding it to the collection, then updating the properties. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247038.aspx has them all listed.

Comment: @eirikb may I ask how you created the content type? I cannot find any information on the format of the data to POST to _api/Web/ContentTypes

Comment: @claesv I didn't. I ended up using JSOM. My app mixes both JSOM and REST. It's an Angular app so I wrap `ClientContext` in a promise, so they interchange fluently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limitations on adding FieldLinks to a Content Type via REST. What you're attempting may not be possible at the moment. Here are the limitations:

- Site Columns cannot be added to a content type using the REST
  service.
- You can add a field to a site content type only if the field already
  exists on the parent content type.
- You can add a field to a content type associated with a list only if
  the field already exists on the list. To add a completely new field
  to a list content type, you have to first add it to the list and then
  add it to the content type in a separate call to the REST service.

Taken from the documentation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj245869.aspx#postsyntax

Comment: I'm not a big fan of **"It's not possible"**, but the question has been out for some time now and your sources are solid. Thanks for the answer =)